# Error While using schedule_selector in Cococs2d-x

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

When i am using this

```
   void addCats();//Declareation in .h file
   this->schedule( schedule_selector(HelloWorld::addCats()), 2.0 );//addCats is a function
```

It Working Fine addCats function call every time, But When i am using

```
 //In.h file
 void addCats(int);
 //In.cpp file
 int i=10;
 this->schedule( schedule_selector(HelloWorld::addCats(i)), 2.0 );
```

Then it give error :: lvalue is required as unary '&' operand.
Please Clearify it, what is the issue, how it work....

And please refer any link or PDF for Cocos2d-X tutorial & study...

Thank you vey much....

Answer (score 2):

Hi I also tried this and ran into the problem.. After a bit of googling and looking into structure I found why this is working like this..
When you go deep in its structure.. It converts it as

```
addCats(CCTime time)
```

You can not assign a variable in C++ like this instead it is actually a comparison with your time 2.0 given.

So try your method like this

```
//In.h file
 void addCats(cocos2d::ccTime time);
 //In.cpp file

this->schedule( schedule_selector(HelloWorld::addCats), 2.0 );
addCats(CCTime time)
{

}
```

Use a break point in your method. You will come to know that your `time` value is 2.0 .
This lvalue problem arises when you assign when you need to compare. 
Hope this helps. :)